# Is this PHP script secure?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I'm trying to create a secure website. Can someone let me know if this is susceptible to SQL injection? If it is, could you provide me with an exmaple of a statement that would work for injection? I've tried to inject it myself but my connection just times out. Thanks.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);


$db->query("INSERT INTO Name(Name) VALUES ('$firstname')");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not do code review. We can talk about concepts and approaches, but not about specific issues in specific code.

Comment: Okay no problem. I thought it would be more relevant to post this here rather than Stack Overflow but I can try there instead. Thanks.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no sanitation or escaping of quotes found in your snippet assuming `$firstname` is user provided input. Nothing is stopping me from modifying your query. This [OWASP article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OTG-INPVAL-005%29#Standard_SQL_Injection_Testing) will explain how easy it would be and their example closely resembles what you are trying to do.

You should consider reading up on how to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [filtering your input](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp) to harden your code.

Comment: Do you know why my connection times out when I attempt SQL injection? I have reviewed that page previously and tried to input `1' or '1' = '1` into my form which should be the easiest way to test, but I get a connection reset error in Google Chrome.